# C++ 11 Curly Braces

Tags: c++, c++11, syntax

I haven't used C++ for a good few years, and have just come across this:

```
program.build({ default_device })
```

The definition is:

```
cl_int build(
    const VECTOR_CLASS<Device>& devices,
    const char* options = NULL,
    void (CL_CALLBACK * notifyFptr)(cl_program, void *) = NULL,
    void* data = NULL) const
```

What are the curly braces there for? I have never seen them used in a function call like this before. I assume it has something to do with the function pointer, but that seems optional?

Comment: How do you initialize a vector with a list of elements?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`std::vector` has a constructor that takes an `std::initializer_list`.

An initializer_list can be expressed with curly braces.

So this code creates a vector with one `default_device` in it and passes it to the `build` member function.

Comment: Just FYI, `std::initializer_list` is new in C++11.  Many STL containers, including `std::vector`, have been updated to support `std::initializer_list` as input during construction.

Comment: Thank you for: "An initializer_list can be expressed with curly braces"

Comment: How did you know that `VECTOR_CLASS` is `std::vector`?

Comment: @BЈовић Given the example code and the name, it is most likely either an std::vector or something that looks like it

Answer (score 14):

In:

```
program.build({ default_device })
```

you are automagically instantiating a temporary `VECTOR_CLASS<Device>` object. It is equivalent to:

```
program.build(VECTOR_CLASS<Device>{ default_device })
```

which is equivalent to:

```
program.build(std::vector<Device>{ default_device })
```

which will call [the `std::initializer_list` constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector):

```
std::vector::vector(std::initializer_list<T> init, 
    const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());
```

Comment: `program.build({ default_device })` *here* is equivalent to `program.build(VECTOR_CLASS<Device>{ default_device })`: The former is copy-list-initialization whereas the second is direct-list-initialization. There's a subtle difference e.g. for explicit ctors.

Answer (score 3):

These are initializer lists, se e.g. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/initializer_list/initializer_list/